# BLE 128b Service UUID

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I have the following 128 bit service UUID:

0000FFE0-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

AFAIK, this is basically the base UUID of 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, thus, this can be simplified into the 16 bit UUID of "FFE0".

I can't find this 16 bit UUID in any of the predefined lists (https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf), though, which leads me to believe that the manufactures of this particular BLE module are being a bit naughty and incorrectly defining a 128-bit UUID?

Have I missed something ?

Comment: It is correctly defined UUID. But this one is manufacturer specific one.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear to be a custom service in the [Bluetooth SIG reserved range](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery/).

If a [custom service](https://www.novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/) is created it should use a UUID outside of that range.